# Change default validation_client_name on chef-client to "orgname-validator"

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I need to change default attibute validation_client_name on my chef-server to my orgname-validator, cause it makes an error while bootstraping my nodes:

```
Chef encountered an error attempting to create the client "mynode-1"

 Authentication Error:
 ---------------------
 Failed to authenticate to the chef server (http 401).

 Server Response:
 ----------------
 Invalid signature for user or client 'chef-validator'

 Relevant Config Settings:
 -------------------------
 chef_server_url         "https://chef.myorgname.com/organizations/orgname"
 validation_client_name  "chef-validator"
 validation_key          "/etc/chef/validation.pem"

 If these settings are correct, your validation_key may be invalid.

 [2015-04-02T15:30:44+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
 Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 1.426514217 seconds
 [2015-04-02T15:30:44+00:00] ERROR: 401 "Unauthorized"
 [2015-04-02T15:30:44+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

How can I do that?

Chef-Server 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can at any time, via the Chef server web interface, reset your keys. A popup box will display your new key which you can cut/paste into your validation.pem file.

Also, I'm fairly sure you are missing a client_key, but that might not be it. Have you tried downloading the starter kit that comes default from the Chef server web interface? It comes with all this stuff pre-baked.

Comment: If I manually change client.rb config to `validation_client_name  "orgname-validator"` and then start chef-client, it creates a node & client on my chef-server, and everything works just fine.. So how can I make `validation_client_name  "orgname-validator"` a default config for bootstraping?

Comment: @Blasterdick please post client.rb and knife.rb

Comment: With my client.rb & knife.rb I can manage nodes/clients/recipes/ect., but when I bootstrap new node, chef set validation_client_name on it with "chef-validator", and after that node gets 401 error from chef-server.

Comment: @Blasterdick have you changed the config `validation_client_name` to

`validation_client_name = 'orgname-validator'` ?

Comment: On my chef-server to `/etc/opscode/chef-server.rb` I added line `opscode_erchef['validation_client_name'] = "orgname-validator"`, but it doesn't change the default value on bootstraped nodes. If I manually change `validation_client_name` on the new node to `"orgname-validator"` and then run `sudo chef-client` - it creates node & client on the server & then I can normaly run `chef-client -o 'recipe[myrecipe]'`.